# Fill missing values error in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, error-handling, missing-data

I have a dataframe with quite a few URLs. However, some are missing. It basically looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
csv = [{"url_1" : np.NaN, "url_2" : "https://www.mercedes-benz.de/content/germany/mpc/mpc_germany_website/de/home_mpc/passengercars/home/new_cars/models/mercedes_amg_gt/r190.html"}]

df = pd.DataFrame(csv)
```

In this case, `url_1` is missing. I am trying to replace it with the entries in column `url_2`. This is what I do:

```
df.url_1 = df.url_1.fillna(df.url_2, inplace=True)
```

This is the result:

```
    url_1   url_2
0   None    https://www.mercedes-benz.de/content/germany/m...
```

I have two questions:

(1) Why isn't the missing value replaced?

(2) In the original data set I am thrown an error: `invalid fill value with a <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` The dataframe looks exactly the same  - and I at least do not get an error in the small test I presented above. What does the error tell me and how do I get rid of it?

Any help is gladly appreciated! Thank you, /R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need remove `inplace` if want assign output, because if `inplace` parameter function return `None`:

```
df.url_1 = df.url_1.fillna(df.url_2)
print (df)
                                               url_1  \
0  https://www.mercedes-benz.de/content/germany/m...   

                                               url_2  
0  https://www.mercedes-benz.de/content/germany/m...  

print (df.url_1.fillna(df.url_2, inplace=True))
None
```

Or dont assign and use `inplace`:

```
df.url_1.fillna(df.url_2, inplace=True)
print (df)
                                               url_1  \
0  https://www.mercedes-benz.de/content/germany/m...   

                                               url_2  
0  https://www.mercedes-benz.de/content/germany/m...
```

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!

Answer (score 1):

(1) & (2)

You can't use assignation and the keyword inplace

```
df['url_1'] = df['url_1'].fillna(df['url_2'])
# or
df['url_1'].fillna(df['url_2'], inplace=True)
```

This should solve both problems.